# Imagemagick conversion process

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I was trying to resize a pdf file to 8.5x11 with ImageMagick and in doing so, I am loosing the quality of my pdf file.

I was using *convert source.pdf -extent 612x792 destination.pdf* command.
Can someone please help me with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick uses Ghostscript and will rasterize your PDF. It will not maintain its vectors.  If you want higher quality, use a higher -density to rasterize and then resize back to whatever you want. For example, I use a density 4x the default of 72 or 288 and then resize by 25%=1/4 to get back to the nominal size.

```
convert -density 288 -units pixelsperinch image.pdf -resize 25% result.pdf
```

You can then include your -density 72 -gravity XX -extent 612x792 before the output.

Or you can compute do -density 288 etc and then just resize to 612x792.

Comment: Okay. I tried with this script -> convert source.pdf -gravity Center -extent 612x792 output.pdf. It created a 8.5x11 PDF but, the quality has completely gone.

Comment: You did not include the higher density and the resize as per my answer! Why not?

Comment: Yes. I tried including density 300. But it didn't work. I lost the quality.

Comment: Post your PDF file. I have never had any issues doing what I suggested. I need to try your PDF myself.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not allowing me to attach files. Is there any other way to send this file to you?

Comment: Zip it and post it to some free image hosting service. Then put the URL in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick is rasterizing the PDF, then scaling it, then producing an output PDF of differing dimensions, which contains raster data only.

Scale a PDF to fit directly like this:

`cpdf -scale-to-fit "612 792" in.pdf -o out.pdf`

This keeps the PDF's original vector artwork and fonts intact.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this and it worked.

```
convert -density 300 -define pdf:fit-page=Letter -gravity Center source.pdf output.pdf
```